# how can I handle both winforms listview click and doubleclick events?

Tags: c#, winforms

My application is as follows

program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsClickAndDoubleClick
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Form1.cs

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsClickAndDoubleClick
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

      

        private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Double click");
        }

        private void listView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Single click");
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.Designer.cs

```
namespace WindowsFormsClickAndDoubleClick
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("one");
            System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("two");
        
            this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
            this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // listView1
            // 
            this.listView1.HideSelection = false;
            this.listView1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[] {
            listViewItem1,
            listViewItem2,
          });
            this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(97, 56);
            this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
            this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(254, 134);
            this.listView1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.List;
            this.listView1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_Click);
            this.listView1.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_DoubleClick);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.listView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
          
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
    }
}
```

I want to handle both click and doubleclick events
Yet I can only get the Click Event Message Showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to handle both `Click` and `Double-Click` and perform different actions, or prevent one from activating the same action twice, you can delay the execution of the code in the `Click` handler, based on the [SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.doubleclicktime) value (it can be set by a user based of preferences).

Then, perform an action in the `Click` handler in case the `Double-Click` action has not been performed.

<sub>(The reason why you cannot *see* both handlers in action has already been explained)</sub>

```
bool doubleClicked = false;

private async void listView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime);

    if (doubleClicked) {
        Console.WriteLine("ListView Click - Already Double-Clicked");
        doubleClicked = false;
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("ListView Click");
    }
}

private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doubleClicked = true;
    Console.WriteLine("ListView Double-Click");
}
```

Comment: This does actually answer my question. I can substitute MessageBox.Show successfully for the console writeline.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are *blocking* on the *single click*

That's to say, you're blocking the *message pump* (*UI*) on the *single click* (with a `MessageBox`), the system will not be able to recognise to the *double click.* It surpasses the time it considers *the next click* (which was held up while the dialog is showing) as part the *double click* sequence.

Instead, use a `Debug.WriteLine` and view the results in your [*output window*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/output-window?view=vs-2019)

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Double click");
}

private void listView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Single click");
}
```

A great comment from [Jakob Busk Sørensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2445415/jakob-busk-s%C3%B8rensen)

> This also means that there are limits to what you can use single click
> for, if you also want to use double click. Basically anything that
> runs on single click, will also run on double click. Alternatively
> consider using right click, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: This also means that there are limits to what you can use single click for, if you also want to use double click. Basically anything that runs on single click, will also run on double click. Alternatively consider using right click, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: @JakobBuskSørensen added your comment to the answer with attribution